# Colocar label com duas linhas em chartjs

Tags: javascript, chartjs

Tenho [esse gráfico](http://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/y4trpr15/1/) onde uso [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) e gostaria de colocar uma label com duas linhas, `\n` nem `<br/>` tem funcionado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por enquanto isso não é possível por 'meios oficiais'. Há algumas discussões e issues no repositório oficial sobre isso. Isso já tá marcado em milestones pra vir em versões futuras. Veja o progresso das discussões no github nessas issues: [#358](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/358), [#123](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/608).